# Creating all subsets recursively without using array

Tags: algorithm, recursion, subset, powerset

We get non negative integer number `n` from user and we must print all subsets of set `({1,2,3,...,n})`. (`n<=20`)

for example for `n=3` we must print:

```
{1 , 2 , 3}
{1 , 2}
{1 , 3}
{1}
{2 , 3}
{2}
{3}
{}
```

`,`s are optional and the sequence can be printed without any comma. (like {1 2 3})
I must add that the sequence of subsets must be exactly like the example. Meaning first the subsets that have 1, then subsets that have 2 and .... The longest subset must be printed first. (lexicographical from the largest subset (the set itself) to null set)

I see a lot of codes in the Internet that solve this problem with arrays or using a bit array that indicate whether we use a number or not. The issue is that in this question, we are not allowed to use -any- type of array or other data structures like vector ,etc. Even using the array behaviour of something like string is completely prohibited. It must be solved only with recursion.

We are also not allowed to use any advanced functions. For example if we write it with `C`, we are allowed just to use `stdio.h` or for `C++`, only `<iostream>` is allowed and no other library.

I don't know how to do this without any arrays. How to check which number it must print and at the sametime, manage the `{}`.

PS1.
The question is simply generation powerset with these conditions:

USING ARRAY, STRING AND EVEN LOOPS ARE COMPLETELY PROHIBITED. JUST RECURSION.

User Kosyr submitted a very good answer with bit operators. So if you want to submit another answer, submit an answer that even doesn't use bit operators.

PS2.

I write this code by help of George but it doesn't works fine. It doesn't have something like 1 2 4. It also repeats some cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void printAllSets (int size)
  {printRows (size, 1);}

void printRows (int size , int start)
{
  if (start<=size)
  {printf( "{ ");
  printRow (start, size);
  printf ("}");
  printf ("\n");}
  if (start <= size)
  {printRows(size -1 , start);
    printRows (size , (start + 1));}
}
printRow (int start, int limit)
{

  if (start <= limit)
  {

    printf ("%d ",start);
    printRow (start +1, limit);
  }
}


int main()
{
    printAllSets(5);
    printf("{ }");
    return 0;
}
```

PS3.

User Kosyr submitted a very good answer with bit operators. So if you want to submit another answer, submit an answer that even doesn't use bit operators.

Comment: Hint: print all the subsets of length zero, then print all the subsets of length 1, etc. until finally print the only subset of length n.

Comment: @thebjorn I don't know how to do this. I must add that the sequence of subsets must be exactly like the example. Meaning first the subsets that have 1, then subsets that have 2 and .... The longest subset must be printed first. not just length zero. then length 1 and ...

Comment: what is max `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive algorithms are very memory intensive. Here algorithm for `n <= 31`

```
#include <iostream>

void bin(unsigned bit, unsigned k, unsigned max_bits) {
    if (bit == max_bits) {
        std::cout << "{";
        bin(bit - 1, k, max_bits);
    }
    else {
        if ((k & (1u << bit)) != 0) {
            std::cout << (max_bits - bit) << " ";
        }
        if (bit != 0) {
            bin(bit - 1, k, max_bits);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void print(unsigned k, unsigned n, unsigned max_bits) {
    bin(max_bits, k, max_bits);
    if (k != 0) {
        print(k - 1, n, max_bits);
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    std::cin >> n;
    print((1u << n) - 1u, 1u<<n, n);
    return 0;
}
```

First recursion `print` enumerates `k` from `2^n-1` to `0`, second recursion `bin` enumerates all bits of `k` and print non-zero bits. For example, `max_bits = 5` and `k = 19` is `10011b = 16 + 2 + 1 = 2^4 + 2^1 + 2^0`, bits `4,1,0` interoperate as set `{5-4,5-1,5-0} => {1,4,5}`

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you edit is somehow that it will print the largest ones first. I mean like my example, lexicographically from the biggest subset (the set itself)  to null set? I am new to programming and It is the first time I need to use these bit operators. Also n<=20.

Comment: Also another question: Is there any way to solve this without bit operators? (And Also not using loop and array). I mean something like hanoi tower problem? Also I must add that n<=20.

Comment: Updated the source for lexicographical ordering. I can't solve it recursively without arrays and bits, but `n<=20` hints us to use bits :)

Comment: Thank you again! If there is no answers without bits in two days, I will accept your answer as the best answer. Thank you again.

Comment: recursive algorithms can become translated by a sufficiently optimizing compiler or interpreter if they are written as pure functions that recurse only at the end of an execution path using a technique call "tail call optimization".

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to loops is recursion.

To solve this problem (I think...haven't tested it), I investigate the problem by tabulating the sample date and discerned three states, `Size`, `Start`, and `Limit` with progression as follows:

```
Size  Start Limit   Output
  10      1    10    1..10
  10      1     9     1..9
              ...      ...
  10      1     1        1
  10      2    10    2..10
  10      2     9     2..9
              ...      ...
  10      2     2        2
        ...   ...      ...
  10     10    10       10
```

The following recursive algorithm in pseudo code may do the trick:

```
printAllSets size
  printRows size 1

printRows size start
  print "{"
  printRow start size
  print "}"
  print CRLF
  if start <= size
    printRows size (start + 1)

printRow start limit
  if start <= limit
    print start + SPACE
    printRow start (limit - 1)
```

Hope this at least helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank You. your pseudo code had some problems that I edited in my program. but your answer doesn't cover something like 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10. (it doesn't have 6 but has all other numbers). Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @titansarus Your question specifically says that it's a set of integers in the range [1,n]. By that formulation, your 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 dillemma is moot.

Comment: @erip I Said that for n = 10. For example {1 , 2 , 3 ,4 , 5 ,7 , 8 , 9 ,10} is a subset of {1 , 2, ... , 10} but the above algorithm don't generate that. My question is generation of Power Set without loop,array and string... using just pure recursion. I checked a lot of algorithms in the internet but even the most simple of them used at least loop or string. I found nothing that satisfies all of my problem conditions at once.

Comment: @titansarus I have added another answer after some thought. It is rather elegant though not tail call optimized (something you can probably contribute). It defines `powerset (k+1)` in terms of `powerset k`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can solve this iteratively, which we can assume could also be converted to recursion, although it seems unnecessary. Consider that we can unrank any of the combinations given its index, using common knowledge. So all we need to do is count how many earlier combinations we are skipping and how many we need to unrank at each stage of the iteration (I may have missed something in the following but I think the general idea is sound):

```
Skip 0, unrank from `3 choose 3`
`2 choose 2` combinations
{1 , 2 , 3} 

Skip 0, unrank from `3 choose 2`
`2 choose 1` combinations
{1 , 2}
{1 , 3}

Skip 0, unrank from `3 choose 1`
`2 choose 0` combinations
{1}

Skip `3 choose 2 - 2 choose 2`,
unrank from `3 choose 2`
`1 choose 1` combinations
{2 , 3}

Skip `3 choose 1 - 2 choose 1`,
unrank from `3 choose 1`
`1 choose 0` combinations
{2}

Skip `3 choose 1 - 1 choose 1`,
unrank from `3 choose 1`
`0 choose 0` combinations
{3}

Empty set
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the powerset of a set `k`, `powerset k`, is the set of all possible sets containing elements from that given set including the empty set itself. Clearly, when `k` is the empty set `powerset []` is simply the set containing the empty set, `[ [] ]`. Now, given a power set of `k`, `powerset k`, the powerset for `k` plus an additional element, `E`, `powerset (K+E)`, would include all possible sets containing elements without `E`, `powerset k`, plus those same elements except now all containing `E`

pseudo code...

```
let powerset k =
   match k with
   | [] -> [[]]
   | x:xs -> x * powerset xs + powerset xs
```

or with tail call equivalent performance

```
let powerset k =
   let (*) e ess = map (es -> e::es) ess
   reduce (e ess -> (e * ess) ++ ess) [ [] ] (reverse k)
```

....(In F#)

```
let rec powerset k =
  match k with
  | []    -> [ [] ]
  | x::xs -> 
      let withoutE = powerset xs
      let withE = List.map (fun es -> x::es) withoutE
      List.append withE withoutE
```

or more succinctly

```
let rec powerset = function
  | []    -> [ [] ]
  | x::xs -> List.append (List.map (fun es -> x::es) (powerset xs)) (powerset xs)
```

A better version would allow for tail call optimization...which we achieved using common functional patterns:

```
let rec powerset2 k = 
  let inline (++) a b = List.concat [a;b]
  let inline (+*) a bs = List.map (fun b -> a::b) bs
  List.fold 
    (fun ac a -> (a +* ac) ++ ac)
    [ [] ] 
    (List.rev k)
```

-- this all took me a while to rediscover. It was a fun little puzzle. :)